# Why does the font tag require extra quotes when the font name contains a hyphen?

Tags: html, fonts

I (am somewhat embarrassed to) have a question about the `font` tag, and how it handles font names that contain a hyphen.

My friend had the following font tag on his web site. But it did not render the text in the "Handwriting - Dakota" font.

```html
<font face="Handwriting - Dakota">Hello, World</font>
```

Adding another layer of quotes fixed the problem. Here, the `face` attribute (which is double quoted) consists of a single-quoted string. This text *does* render in the Dakota font.

```html
<font face="'Handwriting - Dakota'">Hello, World</font>
```

Now, clearly the right thing to do here is replace the `font` tag with a `span`. But I'm curious as to why the first form didn't work. According to the HTML 4.01 spec, the [face attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT) is a comma-separated list of font names; it doesn't say anything about hyphens. Nor does the spec for [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata) (the data type of the face attribute).

Note that it appears to be the hyphen, not the spaces, that causes the need for two layers of quotes. `face="American Typewriter"` works just fine.

What's special about the hyphen that requires a second layer of quotes? And is this caused by an HTML parsing rule that applies to things besides the `font` tag (that is, can one run into a similar situation in modern HTML)?

**update**: So there are a bunch of variations of Dakota out there, and they don't all have hyphens in the name. The issue can be reproduced more reliably with [Lane](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Lane), a font available on Font Squirrel. `face="'Lane - Narrow'"` works; `face="Lane - Narrow"` does not.

Comment: In which browser(s) on which platform(s) does this happen? I cannot reproduce it in Firefox, Chrome, IE on Win 7 using a font named ALPHA-Demo. Maybe it’s the combination of spaces and hyphen that triggers the problem, but I don’t have a font with a name containing a hyphen with spaces around,

Comment: Are you sure the name of the font is with a space dash space? I think you now are referring to a file name and not the attribute font name in the font file. I think the font name as stored in the font itself is used in your systems font dialogues. I guess the font name should be `Handwriting Dakota`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I've reproduced this on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome on Mac OS X Yosemite. And, for anyone who wants to try to reproduce this, Dakota is a free font that's available from several sites.

Comment: And, @allcaps, the font does indeed have a hyphen in its name -- that's how the name of the font (not the filename) appears in Font Book and in the Mac OS font picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the browsers are using the `face` attribute of the `font` tag to populate the `font-family` CSS property. So `face="'Handwriting - Dakota'"` becomes `font-family: 'Handwriting - Dakota'`. However, `face="Handwriting - Dakota"` becomes `font-family: Handwriting - Dakota`, which is invalid CSS.

According to the [CSS spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/fonts.html#font-family-prop):

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or **unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers**. This means most punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names.

So, `<font face="American Typewriter">` worked because the font name is a valid sequence of CSS identifiers. But since a bare hyphen is not a valid CSS identifier ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization)), the font name must be a quoted string. (Or the hyphen must be escaped; it turns out that `<font face="Handwriting \- Dakota">` works, too.) Similarly, `<font face="3dumb">`doesn't work because CSS identifiers can't start with a number. ([3dumb](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/3Dumb) is another Font Squirrel font.)

Answer (score 1):

There are no special parsing rules for the `face` attribute. If we have `<font face="'Handwriting - Dakota'">`, then this is parsed so that the font name is `'Handwriting - Dakota'` with the Ascii apostrophes at the start and end as part of the name. Thus, it would seem that in your system, the font really has such a name.

However, font names are an obscure topic, and there is no official definition for the meaning of “name of the font” in this context. In the CSS context, in the `font-family` property value, the value is in principle well-defined (we can use either the full name or the PostScript name), but browsers may differ.

If the font in your system is what you got along with Mac OS, it may carry names different from the font vendor’s name. And a name with “ - ” in it may cause problems in browsers. They could be fixed by renaming the font, but that would not  help when other people view your pages. If you have observed that using CSS instead fixes the problem, then I suggest that you forget the problem.

I found a [discussion](http://www.dafont.com/forum/read/132217/all-font-websites-have-the-corrupt-version-of-a-font-dakota-regular) that seems to mean that the vendor’s (vLetter, Inc) name for the font is Dakota and they [distribute](https://www.vletter.com/downloads/dakota-font-download-free.html) it for free (though you need to give personal details; I even needed to fill in “-” as the state). I downloaded it and installed it, as a normal font, in Win 7. It works normally, both with `<font face=Dakota>` and in CSS (tested on Chrome, IE, Firefox).

It might be safest to use Dakota as downloaded from the vendor’s site and use it as a web font with `@font-face`. That way you would be using the newest version, and almost all users would see it (as opposite to the rather limited set of users who have some version of Dakota as installed in their systems).

Comment: I appreciate your detective work and thorough answer (and +1 for that), but  the ASCII apostrophes aren't part of the font name on my system.